# Correct the float values

Tags: php, floating-point

I read some data from a csv file. Each line in the file has a float value. these values can be either:

> - .123 : starting with a period, so I need to add a zero before.
> - 1,23: having a delimter comma ',' instead of period so I need to    change that.
> - 1.2e3 having an exponential-format so I need to convert it to decimal format.

I can't use the function `number_format` because I can't set the number of decimal points (the float numbers don't have a fixed length of the decimal part and we want to take them as they are to not lose data).

Here is what I tried so far; I built two functions, the first one filters the floats, the second one corrects them when the filter returns false:

```
function validateFloat($float){
  if(!filter_var($float,FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT,array('flags' => FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION))){
    return false;
  }

}

function correctFloat($float){
  if (validateFloat($float)==false){
    $number = number_format($float,null,'.');
    str_replace($number,'',$line);
  }
}
```

I don't know how to build the `correctFloat` function. Any suggestions ? Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function can check if there is a comma and get the correct deliminator then use floarval on any other case

```
function change_format($value){
    if(is_string($value)){
        //has to be a string if using ','
        $value= str_replace(",",".",$value);
    }
    return floatval($value);
} 

echo change_format(.123) ."<br>";
echo change_format("1,23") ."<br>";
echo change_format("1.2e3");
```

Outputs:

```
0.123
1.23
1200
```

Comment: floatval pads it. Use the update I just made misspelled `$value` a lot...

Comment: I'll in the next 9 hours, I have reached my votes daily limit :)

Comment: How to write the str_replace into the csv file ?

Comment: @Somar not sure what you mean that does not appear to be part of the original question.

Comment: Yes it does, from the title: *then replace them in the file* and what I mean is search the value in the file and replace it with the correct one.

Comment: You might want to split that out that would make this question very large. I am not even sure what your file looks like here or how you are accessing it.

Comment: @Somar Split the content (after getting its contents using fgetcsv() ) using explode()
then you can move through array, you can try in following manner





$file = fopen("data.csv","r");
$dataString = fgetcsv($file);
fclose($file);
$data = explode(chr(10), $dataString);
foreach($data as $row) {
$rowValues = explode(',', $row);
foreach($rowValues as $singleData) {
// do here whatever you want or just call change_format function
}
}

Comment: @nerdlyist [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42208643/write-the-correct-value-of-a-float-to-a-csv-file) is the new question