# Write the correct value of a float to a csv file

Tags: php, csv

In the csv file, I have lines with this structure :

```
Name;timestamp;floatValue
Name;timestamp;floatValue
Name;timestamp;floatValue
...
```

In my code, I check each value in the line, I filter them,then I want to correct the float value by calling the function `floatval`, because I have wrong values sometimes like : .904 or 2,454 and using this function returns the right formatted one.

```
    <?php

    if (($handle = fopen('file.csv', "r+")) !== false) {
        while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ";")) !== false) {

          $headers = [
              'name',
              'timestamp',
              'floatValue',
          ];
          $line = array_combine($headers, $line);
          $args = array('name' => array('filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
                                                      'options' => array('regexp' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9_:.()\/]*$/'), ),
                        'timestamp' => array('filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK,
                                                            'options' => 'validateDate', ),
                         'floatValue' => array('filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT),);
    $result = filter_var_array($line, $args);
    $line = correctFloat($line);
    print_r($line);
    }

    }

    fclose($handle);

    function validateDate($date)
    {
      if (!preg_match("/^\d{8}$/", substr($date, 0, 8))) {
          return false;
      }
      if (!checkdate(substr($date, 4, 2), substr($date, 6, 2), substr($date, 0, 4))) {
          return false;
      }
      if (substr($date, 8, 2) > 23 || substr($date, 10, 2) > 59 || substr($date, 12, 2) > 59) {
          return false;
      }

      return true;
    }


function correctFloat($line){
  $float = $line['floatValue'];
  $value = str_replace(",",".",$float);
  return str_replace($float,floatval($value),$line);
}


    ?>
```

Now I'm stuck how to write the correct value inside the file in the right line?

I tried this:

```
fwrite($handle,implode(";",correctFloat($line)));
```

But it didn't work. **How to re-write each line into the file in the right position with the correct float without losing data?**
Any idea?

> :::EDIT:::

I also tried to use a temporary file:

```
$temp = tmpfile();
fputcsv($temp,correctFloat($line),';');
fwrite($handle,fread($temp, 1024));
```

but I didn't get a good result. nothing happened inside the file.

**Example**

*Input :*

```
Name;timestamp;.23
Name;timestamp;2,4578
Name;timestamp;1.23
```

*Expected output:*

```
Name;timestamp;0.23
Name;timestamp;2.4578
Name;timestamp;1.23
```

In this example: 2,4578 should be in the output : 2.4578 (I replace the comma with '.' using the `function correctFloat($line)` above )

> **New try:**

```
$newline = correctFloat(array_combine($headers, $line));
array_push($newline,chr(10));
$l = implode(";",$newline);
fwrite($handle,$l);
rewind($handle);
```

Only the first value changes and then the file is refreshing without getting out of the loop.

Comment: you're having all your data corrected in $line, right?

Comment: the function  `correctFloat` returns the correct line but I don't know how to write it back to the file. @kamaldeepsinghbhatia

Comment: fyi, for efficiency the `$headers` and `$args` variables only need to be created once. i.e. they can be moved outside the while loop?

Comment: Just to confirm, is the comma used as a decimal point e.g:  `2,4578` is really `2.4578`. Or is it '24578' (integer 24578)?

Comment: @RyanVincent `2,4578` should be in the output : `2.4578` (I replace the comma with '.')

Comment: Please add that comment about replacing comma with decimal point to  your question. All the relevant information should be in the question. fyi, it is worth deleting comments that have been answered. It is easier for others to follow later.

Comment: You want something like that? https://eval.in/736668

Comment: @RyanVincent Yesssssss, how to do the same but with files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requirements: Given a CSV input file then create an output file that has the float fields formatted correctly.

How:

- Read the input file one record at a time splitting it into `fields`
- Format the floating point string into a valid string ny replacing comma with decimal point.
- Apply some validation to the fields
- format the fields as a valid output string (`correctFloat`)
- append to the output file.

Note: I have used test data so the validation is not checked. This code just formats the output from the input.

[Source code I used](http://pastebin.com/5M6euCmH)

#### Code:

*Input / Output file names:*

```
define('DATA_FILE', 'Q42208643.dat');
define('DATA_FILE_OUT', 'Q42208643.out.dat');
```

*Headers and Validation:*

```
// setup field names and validiation rules
$headers = ['name',  'timestamp', 'floatValue',];

$args = array(
              'sensor_internal_id' => array('filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
                                                      'options' => array('regexp' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9_:.()\/]*$/'), ),
                                                      
              'timestamp' => array('filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK,
                                   'options' => 'validateDate', ),
                                   
               'value' => array('filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT),
        );
```

*Process input and output files:*

```
if (($handle = fopen(DATA_FILE, "r+")) !== false) {

    $fOut = fopen(DATA_FILE_OUT, "wb");

    while (($fields = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ";")) !== false) {

        $fields[2] = str_replace(",", ".", $fields[2]); // ensure float sting is valid

        $namedFields = array_combine($headers, $fields);
        $result = filter_var_array($namedFields, $args);

        $outLine = correctFloat($fields);
        fwrite($fOut, $outLine . PHP_EOL);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    fclose($fOut);
}
```

*functions:*

```
function validateDate($date)
{
  if (!preg_match("/^\d{8}$/", substr($date, 0, 8))) {
      return false;
  }
  if (!checkdate(substr($date, 4, 2), substr($date, 6, 2), substr($date, 0, 4))) {
      return false;
  }
  if (substr($date, 8, 2) > 23 || substr($date, 10, 2) > 59 || substr($date, 12, 2) > 59) {
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}


function correctFloat($fields) {
  $fields[2] = floatval($fields[2]);
  return implode(';', $fields);
}
```

*Sample input:*

```
122222;1487075470;.123
233333;1487075470;2,345
344444;1487075470;3.678
```

*Sample Output:*

```
122222;1487075470;0.123
233333;1487075470;2.345
344444;1487075470;3.678
```

Comment: can `DATA_FILE` and `DATA_FILE_OUT` be the same ? I am testing

Comment: @Somar, Please don't try and write to a text file while reading it. It is certain to cause more hassle than it is worth. Just rename them after processing. i.e. rename input to .save and output to the required input filename. Or pass the filnames as parameters to the processes?

Comment: Why do I get these errors: `PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in $fields[2] = str_replace(",", ".", $fields[2]);` and `PHP Warning:  array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements ` and `PHP Warning:  filter_var_array() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given` I guess the offset one is because I don't always have a comma in the csv lines, so when it searches it, it does not find anything

Comment: Can we use `file_put_contents()` and `file_get_contents()` like that we will be able to work on the variables then put the content again to the same file?

Comment: @Somar, download the source code from the pastebin link. I have added displays of the input / out files and is what I am running here. It works fine. PHP 5.4 on windows XP.

Comment: I  mean use them to write to the same file, first we get the content, modify it and put it in a variable, then put the content again to the same file

Comment: @Somar, sorry forgot to include the Headers / Validation code in the answer ;-/

Comment: Great; that works perfectly, but I really need to write the output to the same file ... thank you very much though. That was really helpful

Comment: I got it simply by adding : `file_put_contents(DATA_FILE,file_get_contents(DATA_FILE_OUT));`
I am  happy finally I accomplished this thing. big thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [rewind()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php)
Example code :

```
$handle = fopen('output.txt', 'r+');

fwrite($handle, 'Really long sentence.');
rewind($handle);
fwrite($handle, 'Foo');
rewind($handle);

echo fread($handle, filesize('output.txt'));

fclose($handle);
```

//
Output:
Foolly long sentence.

Here rewind function will take you at the start of current line then you just need to replace all characters in that line
[Note : if your current data is less then old data then you'll see old values appended at the end so just replace all remaining characters with '' (blank)

Let me know if it helped otherwise I'll provide the way to use it in your code

Comment: I appreciate it, but there is one problem here,  `rewind()` is not letting me get out of while loop. How to solve that ?

Comment: Tried it and it appends the second line with the float of the first line

Comment: @Somar add `chr(10)` at the end of your `$line` like this : `$line.chr(10)` . chr(10) is end of line in most of csv files